# Does this Dell 'driverless' dock work with Ubuntu?

Tags: multiple-monitors, dell, hdmi, usb-c

Dell sell this "USB-C 8-in-1 Driverless Mobile Dock" which includes HDMI video out
https://www.dell.com/en-uk/shop/usb-c-8-in-1-driverless-mobile-dock/apd/ab808698/pc-accessories#tabs_section
Dell lists the operating systems which this works on, but does not include Linux or Ubuntu.

Given that it is 'driverless', I can't really see how the OS could/should affect this (but I know nothing about the internals of HDMI).
Has anybody tried to connect this to a Dell laptop and got it to work on HDMI out?
I'd be especially keen to know if you've managed to use this to attach a *second* HDMI monitor (ie, laptop, directly connected HDMI, plus this HDMI via the USB-C dock).

Alternatively, which of the Dell docks are known to work with Ubuntu?

Comment: It would be nice to believe that somebody else has tried that dock, but perhaps I'm being optimistic?

Answer (score 0):

I have a precision 7520 with the tb16 dock and ubuntu 22.04.1, everything on the dock works.
I went to the dell support website,  gave the service tag, downloaded what drivers they had and used them.